# I am getting this error when build the apps Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, dagger-2

Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.

> 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8) and 'kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' task (current target is 17) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
> Consider using JVM toolchain: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/toolchain

And here is my app gradle file

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
namespace 'com.waltonbd.daggerwithcheezy'
compileSdk 32

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.waltonbd.daggerwithcheezy"
    minSdk 24
    targetSdk 32
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
}

dependencies {

def dagger_version = "2.40.5"

implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'

implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

}
```

Comment: The error means there is a mismatch in the Java version being used for compilation between the `compileDebugJavaWithJava` task and the `kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin` task. Make sure both tasks are using the same Java version.

Comment: Update your Kotlin options to use a higher version of the JVM that supports Java 17.

`kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '17'
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means there is a mismatch in the Java version being used for compilation between the `compileDebugJavaWithJava` task and the `kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin` task.

Make sure both tasks are using the same Java version. Update your Kotlin `options` to use a higher version of the JVM that supports Java 17.

e.g.

```
...
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '17'
}
```