# jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-studio, gradle

I'm getting this error:

> org.gradle.api.GradleException: 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8) and 'kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' task (current target is 17) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.

and I just don't get it. What exactly is it that has incompatible Java versions? Where can I find out the different Java versions for <whatever>?

I have never made a conscious decision about any Java versions and would prefer not to be bothered with it. Anyhow, why is there now some Java version incompatibility? What did I screw up to end up with this? How to fix it?

For context: I'm in the process of updating an old app I haven't touched in over three years. Maybe the update of the gradle plugin introduced this incompatibility?

Actually, I have updated some kotlin version in the projects gradle file. From

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61'
```

to

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.21'
```

Maybe this could be another clue.

Also, I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76777020/i-am-getting-this-error-when-build-the-apps-execution-failed-for-task-appkapt). I tried what was suggested in the answer and added a `kotlinOptions` block in the modules gradle file, experimenting with values `17` and `1.8`, but to no awail. I didn't witness any effect.

This is my `app/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "cyberdynesoftware.tech_tree"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 8
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }
    namespace 'cyberdynesoftware.tech_tree'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:33.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:33.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:33.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.2'
    kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.QuadFlask:colorpicker:0.0.15'
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your `app/build.gradle.kts` file, as well as the Gradle wrapper version used?

Comment: @Edric: That file doesn't exist. No .kts suffix. I've updated gradle to version 8.0.1 I think. No sure where to click to confirm that.

Comment: Either one of `build.gradle`/`build.gradle.kts` rather

Comment: @Edric: I've added `app/build.gradle` to my question.

Comment: Hi did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @PetrNymsa: I simply created a new project and copied my source files over.